# Database profiler for postgresql server to get the detail of each query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, database-design, database-optimization

We need a database profiler for our application which shows the full detail of each query and suggest for indexes etc I found is there any free tool available like Postgres Enterpirse Manager?

Comment: start with `EXPLAIN` - it gives much info on execution and helps with deciding whether is needed

Comment: Databazoo Dev Modeler has a visual `EXPLAIN`, server call profiler and some schema optimization hints. Community version should support PostgreSQL.